# Unable to read incoming deep link iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

Minimum iOS version is 13, Scene delegate file is completely deleted, only using appdelegate. But `open url`, `continue userActivity` and `openURLContexts` methods are not calling in when app opened using deep link.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        
        print("app opened using deep link from \(sourceApplication)")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DeepLink"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    
        return true
    }
    



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity:
            NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    
        print("app opened using deep link ")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DeepLink"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    
        return true
        }



    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        if let url = URLContexts.first?.url{
            print(url)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DeepLink"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)

        }
    }
```

**Edit - 1**

```
Invalid redeclaration of 'application(_:open:options:)'
```

[image]

Comment: Under what class are you writing code?

Comment: appdelegate ....

Comment: If you have eliminated `SceneDelegate` from your project, all you need for deep linking is `application(_:open:options:)` under `AppDelegate`.

Comment: I tried but 'application(_:open:options:)' method is not calling

Comment: Then you are not doing a good job eliminating `SceneDelegate`.

Comment: :( Thanks @ElTomato , let me check it again

Comment: @Codecracker check my answer

Comment: checking Rajan ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Sample App](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m2pzeZi-8ZqOpotfTHjnibHOM4JypCyY/view?usp=sharing) I created to test deep links in minimum iOS 13 without `SceneDelegate`

This is because you might be using wrong open URL method to receive deep links:

The correct one is:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("Deep link received \(url)")
    return true
}
```

continue userActivity is generally called in the case of universal links

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
}
```

So, AppDelegate looks like:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print("Deep link received \(url)")
        return true
    }
}
```

And in **Info.plist** make sure to add URL Schemes.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>deepLinks</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

It looks something like this:
[image]

Then to test your deep links, go to your browser and write your uri scheme with ://

Example in this case:
**deepLinks://mydeeplinkurl**

It will ask you to open your app.

[image]

And you will get a call back in open URL method

[image]

Comment: This is working in sample app @rajan but not in my app.  does firebase involves in this process by any chance?

Comment: First, you need to tell whether it is a deep link or a universal link? Show an example of your link

Comment: only deep link .

Comment: Firebase has nothing to do with deep links. Deep links are called via URI schemes. Firebase handles dynamic links or universal links.
Can you show an example of what link you are tapping?

Comment: if you are using any uri scheme and have defined that uri scheme in your info.plist, then you just need to change the `open url` method.

Comment: i found the probelm Rajan, can you check my question . I just edited it

Comment: It says you are re-declaring your delegate. Check where you have written this delegate and the call back will come there. Don't write this twice

Comment: In app delegate after didFinish launching with options :(

Comment: The error says that you have written this delegate twice. Just keep only one.

Comment: there is an appdelegate extension complicated this , thanks (y)